# Get data sequentially from numpy array in Matlab ordering

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

As an example, suppose, in Matlab, a Matrix `a(2,3,2)` like this:

```
a(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6


a(:,:,2) =

     7     8     9
    10    11    12
```

If I use `mex` and access the elements of this matrix sequentially, I get the following order (in the end, a code to access them sequentially):

```
1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 10, 8, 11, 9, 12
```

Now, if I have the same matrix in numpy

```
In [2]: np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
Out[2]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

, I could try to use `.flatten(...)` to access the items sequentially (couldn't find a better way to do it -- I am open to suggestions). `flatten()` has 4 "ordering" options:

```
In [4]: a.flatten('F')
Out[4]: array([ 1,  7,  4, 10,  2,  8,  5, 11,  3,  9,  6, 12])

In [5]: a.flatten('C')
Out[5]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])

In [6]: a.flatten('A')
Out[6]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])

In [7]: a.flatten('K')
Out[7]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Is there an elegant way to access the elements of the numpy array in a Matlab ordering? (in my real use case, these matrix are big, so copiyng them around wouldn't be preferred)

### Appendix: Code to print the matrix sequentially

[not great, I know, just for testing]

```
  1 void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
  2 {
  3         // This just a test: hardcoding the size of `data_input`
  4         int data_input_size = 12;
  5         double *data_input;
  6         const mxArray *batch_data;
  7 
  8         // Gets a pointer to the first element of batch_data
  9         data_input  = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
 10 
 11         for(int i = 0; i < data_input_size; i++) {
 12                 printf("working_data[i]: %f\n", data_input[i]);
 13         }
 14         plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0, 0, mxREAL);
 15 }
```

Comment: So your matrix in numpy is not equal to your matrix in MATLAB. Checkout the shape of your numpy array.

Comment: Ohh... you are right. It is (2, 2, 3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bugs a lot of people going into NumPy/Python from MATLAB. So, in MATLAB, the indexing format is `(column x row x dim3)` and so on. With NumPy, it's `(axis-0, axis-1, axis-2)` and so on.

To show this schematically using a sample case on MATLAB :

```
>> a = reshape(1:27,[3,3,3]);
>> a
a(:,:,1) =

        row
    --------------->
     1     4     7   |         |
     2     5     8   | col     |
     3     6     9   v         |
a(:,:,2) =                     |
    10    13    16             | dim3
    11    14    17             |
    12    15    18             |
a(:,:,3) =                     |
    19    22    25             |
    20    23    26             |
    21    24    27             v
```

On NumPy :

```
In [62]: a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)

In [63]: a
Out[63]: 

            axis=2
         ---------->
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],   |          |
        [ 3,  4,  5],   | axis=1   |
        [ 6,  7,  8]],  v          |
                                   |
       [[ 9, 10, 11],              |
        [12, 13, 14],              | axis=0
        [15, 16, 17]],             |
                                   |
       [[18, 19, 20],              |
        [21, 22, 23],              |
        [24, 25, 26]]])            v
```

Let's try to correlate these dimensions and axes terminology for the `3D` array case listed in the question between these two *environments* :

```
MATLAB      NumPy
------------------
cols        axis-1
rows        axis-2
dim3        axis-0
```

Thus, to simulate the same behavior in NumPy as MATLAB, we need the axes in NumPy as : `(1,2,0)`. Together with NumPy's way of storing elements starting from the last axis to the first one i.e. in reversed order, the required axes order would be `(0,2,1)`.

To perform the permuting of axes that way, we could use [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) and thereafter use a flattening operation with [`np.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)  -

```
a.transpose(0,2,1).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [515]: a
Out[515]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])

In [516]: a.transpose(0,2,1) # Permute axes
Out[516]: 
array([[[ 1,  4],
        [ 2,  5],
        [ 3,  6]],

       [[ 7, 10],
        [ 8, 11],
        [ 9, 12]]])

In [517]: a.transpose(0,2,1).ravel() # Flattened array
Out[517]: array([ 1,  4,  2,  5,  3,  6,  7, 10,  8, 11,  9, 12])
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Never thought this would be so easy. I spent half a day trying to understand what was happening. The way Matlab and numpy print their outputs was misleading (caused me to think these two matrices were the same).

Comment: Since you are making this very complete, I thought to ask (I tested for this case and it seems to work, but I am unsure): if `size(a)` in Matlab is the same as `a.shape` in Numpy, then `a.ravel()` will generally give me the same ordering? (This is totally not what I expected)

Comment: @vaulttech Same shapes doesn't guarantee that flattened versions (without any permuting of axes) would be the same. That's the whole point of this answer post. That flattening operation with `ravel()`, which is basically `ravel('C')` used in the answer post operates on and flattens the permuted/transposed array.  For a `2D` case, it would be `a.transpose(0,1).ravel()` or simply `.ravel('F')`. For a `4D` case it, would be different and so on.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: It actually does. I had confused it because of the two dimensions of size "2" in my example. I will only need to think a little to digest this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it is straight forward for 4D and higher to have for example 
a.transpose(0,3,2,1) and so on, to create a generic way where you just give a dimension n =4 and can automatically construct the order for transpose(....) ?

Answer (score 2):

This is intended as a suplement to `@Divakar's` answer.

In Octave I made `x` and `a` and saved them to a file

```
>> x=[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 10, 8, 11, 9, 12]
>> a=reshape(x,2,3,2)

a =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6

ans(:,:,2) =

    7    8    9
   10   11   12
```

I can flatten `a` with (same as your `mex`):

```
>> a(:).'
```

In numpy, with `loadmat` from `scipy.io`

```
In [564]: data = loadmat('test.mat')
In [566]: data['x']
Out[566]: 
array([[  1.,   4.,   2.,   5.,   3.,   6.,   7.,  10.,   8.,  11.,   9.,
         12.]])
In [567]: data['a']
Out[567]: 
array([[[  1.,   7.],
        [  2.,   8.],
        [  3.,   9.]],

       [[  4.,  10.],
        [  5.,  11.],
        [  6.,  12.]]])
```

`ravel` with order 'F' displays the original flat `x`:

```
In [571]: data['a'].ravel(order='F')
Out[571]: 
array([  1.,   4.,   2.,   5.,   3.,   6.,   7.,  10.,   8.,  11.,   9., 12.])
```

To help keep track of shapes I prefer to make them all different.  For example

```
>> x=0:23;
>> a=reshape(x,2,3,4);
```

and `a` displays as

```
ans(:,:,1) =

   0   2   4
   1   3   5
...
ans(:,:,4) =

   18   20   22
   19   21   23
```

It is showing 4 (2,3) matrices.

On the numpy side I get:

```
In [575]: data['a'].shape
Out[575]: (2, 3, 4)
In [577]: data['a']
Out[577]: 
array([[[  0.,   6.,  12.,  18.],
        [  2.,   8.,  14.,  20.],
        [  4.,  10.,  16.,  22.]],

       [[  1.,   7.,  13.,  19.],
        [  3.,   9.,  15.,  21.],
        [  5.,  11.,  17.,  23.]]])
```

This is 2 blocks of (3,4) shape.

```
In [579]: data['a'].ravel('F')
Out[579]: 
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   ...,  23.])
```

I see two key differences between numpy and MATLAB/Octave.  Default order is different, but `numpy` lets you specify `F`.  And display of 3d (and larger) arrays is different.  There's in effect a different notion of 'planes' or blocks.

`np.transpose` changes the shape, strides, and order of an array, while keeping the same data base.

Applied to `a`, it produces a (4,3,2) array with order 'C':

```
In [580]: data['a'].T
Out[580]: 
array([[[  0.,   1.],
        [  2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.]],

 ....
       [[ 18.,  19.],
        [ 20.,  21.],
        [ 22.,  23.]]])
In [581]: data['a'].T.ravel()
Out[581]: 
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3., ...22.,  23.])
```

The MATLAB display can be replicated with:

```
In [584]: for i in range(4):
     ...:     print(data['a'][:,:,i])
     ...:     
[[ 0.  2.  4.]
 [ 1.  3.  5.]]
[[  6.   8.  10.]
 [  7.   9.  11.]]
[[ 12.  14.  16.]
 [ 13.  15.  17.]]
[[ 18.  20.  22.]
 [ 19.  21.  23.]]
```