# Interpreting numpy multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am new to numerical computation using numpy. I am having a hard time in understanding arrays with dimentions more than 2. Is there any way to interpret a multidimensional array?
e.g:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,2,2)
>>> arr1
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]],

        [[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]]],


       [[[12, 13],
         [14, 15]],

        [[16, 17],
         [18, 19]],

        [[20, 21],
         [22, 23]]]])
```

Any explanation, reference to build intuition?
Edited:
I wanted to know how to interpret the output of .shape with the output of . i.e in the above example (2,3,2,2) what is the rightmost 2 referring to or 3 or other 2. How numpy handles this?

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41507480/.

Comment: Might also take a look at what a [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) is (Don't be scared by the ugly math, for your purpose you can think of them as the extension of matrices to more dimensions)

Comment: What is it you don't understand - the output, the data, or the concept?

Comment: @Divakar thanks for the link. I can see that the last dim (:,:,x) gives the depth of the array and then from the left->right we get rows or columns or so. i.e (column, row, depth)?

Comment: @Jay.Deka Well NumPy *formally" doesn't have cols or rows, but only axes.But if you have to assign names, I guess you could say the last axis being columns, the second last being rows and then we would need other names for the remaining axes. The MATLAB notation in the post might need a correction it seems as the rows and cols seemed swapped.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, but when I started working with multidimensional arrays, my biggest difficulty was visualizing what the big long streaming list and brackets was all about.  I had a picture in my mind what a 3D and 4D array looked like, but the current representations didn't match what I 'pictured'.  To assist me in viewing the data structures, I wrote a couple of functions to rearrange the structure into a form I could understand.

My question to you then is... do any of the presentations below, help you in understanding or visualizing the structure any better?  I can provide support code in an edit, if any of these are useful.

```
arr1 = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,2,2)

Sample array...
-shape (2, 3, 2, 2), ndim 4
-------------------------
-(0, + (3, 2, 2)
  .  0  1    4  5    8  9  
  .  2  3    6  7   10 11  

-------------------------
-(1, + (3, 2, 2)
  . 12 13   16 17   20 21  
  . 14 15   18 19   22 23
```

Or presentation option 2

```
Alternate format
Main array... 
shape: (2, 3, 2, 2)
[0,...] (3, 2, 2)
  .[[[ 0  1]
  .  [ 2  3]]
  . [[ 4  5]
  .  [ 6  7]]
  . [[ 8  9]
  .  [10 11]]]
[1,...] (3, 2, 2)
  .[[[12 13]
  .  [14 15]]
  . [[16 17]
  .  [18 19]]
  . [[20 21]
  .  [22 23]]]
```

Sorry not to be able to answer your question directly, but often the 'direct' answer isn't what is really needed to get to the root problem,

Comment: I guess the presentation 1 is going to help followed by the second.